# Oracle order by

Tags: oracle

Pessoal boa tarde ao tentar executar o comando abaixo ordenando decrescente ele apresenta o seguinte erro missing expression 
SELECT * FROM tab_estado WHERE nm_uf like'%MG%' and like'%BA%' order by desc ;
Missing expression

Answer (score 2):

O `order by` é utilizado ao lado do nome da coluna utilizada para ordenação. Traduzindo, seria algo como "ordene por colunax". Basta colocar o nome da coluna após o comando `order by` que a consulta vai funcionar.

Comment: eu coloquei SELECT * FROM tab_estado WHERE order by desc nm_uf like'%MG%' and like'%BA%'; mas continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: Para ordernar por nm_uf tem que ser: ...WHERE nm_uf like'%MG%' and nm_uf like'%BA%' order by  nm_uf desc;. Lembre também que o order by é a última coisa que aparece na consulta, ele vem depois dos testes do where.

Comment: obrigado por responder, man ele não rodou SELECT * FROM tab_estado WHERE nm_uf like'%MG%' or like'%BA%' order by nm_uf desc; deo o mesmo erro missing expressão

Comment: Você tá errando no where, tem que ser:  WHERE nm_uf like'%MG%' and nm_uf like'%BA%'. Não pode omitir o nm_uf dos 2 like.

Comment: obrigado era mesmo esse erro rs. TEnho outro problema. Ao tentar executar esse comando no oracle apresenta o seguinte erro missing right parenthesis. Meu comando oracle SELECT  id_banco,vl_saldo  FROM tab_conta WHERE (id_agencia=7 or id_agencia=12 or id_agencia=20) and (vl_saldo<2000,00) and id_banco=2;

Comment: Tira essa vírgula do 2000,00, acredito que deveria usar o ponto(.), a não ser que você tenha colocado um outro locale no banco, diferente do padrão.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab_estado 
WHERE (nm_uf like'%MG%' or nm_uf like'%BA%') 
order by nm_uf desc
```

Ou a cidade é Minas ou é Bahia ...
O order by pede uma coluna.

Comment: então motta como ficaria o meu comando

Comment: Rodou meu sql @Felipe ?

Comment: obrigado era mesmo esse erro rs. TEnho outro problema. Ao tentar executar esse comando no oracle apresenta o seguinte erro missing right parenthesis. Meu comando oracle SELECT id_banco,vl_saldo FROM tab_conta WHERE (id_agencia=7 or id_agencia=12 or id_agencia=20) and (vl_saldo<2000,00) and id_banco=2;

Comment: Parece correto , some os ( e os ) tem de ser igual .... :)

Comment: como assim some os (e os)